# Django annotate a queryset with objects

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have models named Product, Material, and Tag. Each product has many materials, each material has many tags. Each product has tags (not an actual relation) , the tags are defined as all distinct tags of the product's materials. I would like to pass Product queryset with tags attribute to django rest serializer without N+1 problem.

I used subquery, but it only return a row and a column. I tried to operate it at python level, but it produces N+1 problem, and even if I somehow manage to avoid N+1 problem it will be slower than using ORM because it's python. I tried to add tags relation to Product, and update it everytime the material and/or material's tags changed, and query it with prefetch_related so it has no N+1, it works great, but adding more complexities to my code for something that could be so simple. So I prefer to not add tags relation in product.

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Material(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='materials', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    material = models.ForeignKey(Material, related_name='tags', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class TagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Tag
        fields = '__all__'

class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tags = TagSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'
```

I expect to have queryset that can be passed to ProductSerializer without N+1 problem and without using signals.

Comment: You should use `.prefetch_related(..)` here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to load related objects yourself. Django has tooling to do that for you. You can make use of [**`.prefetch_related(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related). This will make queries to retrieve the related objects with an additional query, and then link the objects to the related object. It thus basically performs a JOIN at the Python/Django side and only uses a constant number of queries for these JOINs:

```
products = Product.objects.prefetch_related('materials__tags')
serializer = ProductSerializer(products, many=True)
```

Here we thus avoid fetching the `tags` for each `Product` with another query.

Comment: Yes. However the product doesn't have tags field. I could add it, but it will add complexities to my code because I have to manage the product's tags each time its material and material's tags are changed.

Comment: @linuxnewbie: you do *not* need a `tags` field. Django knows that this is the relation, since the `related_name` is `'tags'` and thus it will properly trigger the join table. So you do *not* need a `tags` field at all :)

Comment: The tags related name is for material not product.

Comment: @linuxnewbie: ah, then it is `materials__tags`.